# Filter Subset Pandas Dataframe by rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter, subset, multiple-columns

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [4,5,6])), 
                  columns=['one','two','three'])

#BelowI am sub setting by rows and columns. But I want to have more than just one column. 
#In this case Column 'One' and 'two'
small=df[df.one==1].one
```

**What is the alternative here?**

Comment: `small=df[df.one==1][["one", "two"]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [4,5,6])), 
              columns=['one','two','three'])

small=df.loc[df.one==1, ["one", "two"]]
# >    one two
#    0  1   2
#    1  1   2
#    2  1   2
```

The first element of  `loc` is the wanted rows ; the second is the wanted columns. As demonstrated here, it allows both masking and indexing.

Comment: Thank You. And this works great. But which method is more efficient and why? The one you pointed out above or df[df.one==1][['one','two']]

Comment: From a time performance perspective, both methods are very close (within 5% from each other). One interesting difference though is that `loc` allows you to slice on columns, like so: `df.loc[df.one==1, "one":"three"]`.

Comment: My bad, they are not even close. `loc` is in fact several times faster on large dataframes.